# Removing Exchange mailbox and archive

Tags: exchange-2010

When I remove an Exchange (2010) mailbox, the mailbox is removed and deleted after the "waiting period" for deleted mailboxes; the AD account is in turn also deleted immediately.

Can anyone confirm what happens to the Archive mailbox?  Does it get deleted immediately, or after the "waiting period" or is it orphaned?

Answer (score 0):

I think this summary explains what you're asking but I'll add some Exchange PowerShell examples below of how to forcefully delete a mailbox if needed but below tells exactly how this works.

> **Summary**
>
> In Exchange, if you delete a mailbox, it is disconnected for a default
>   period of 30 days (the mailbox retention period), and you can
>   reconnect it at any point during that time. Deleting a mailbox does
>   not mean that it is permanently deleted (or purged) from the
>   information store database right away, only that it is flagged for
>   deletion. At the end of the mailbox retention period, the mailbox is
>   permanently deleted from the database. You can also permanently delete
>   the mailbox by choosing to purge it at any time.
>
> This also means that if you mistakenly delete a mail-enabled user
>   account, you can recreate that user object, and then reconnect that
>   mailbox during the mailbox retention period.
>
> Configure the deleted mailbox retention period at the mailbox store
>   object level.
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/274343/how-to-recover-a-deleted-mailbox-in-exchange)</sub>

**PowerShell Examples**

*You'll need to specify the `<ExchangeDBName>` and `<ExchangeMBGuid>` accordingly.*

```
## --// get all information about the mailbox of the deleted user and disconnected mailbox.
Get-MailboxStatistics -Database "<ExchangeDBName>" | Where-Object {$_.DisconnectDate -Notlike $NULL} | FL DisplayName, DisconnectDate, MailboxGuid

## --// get mailboxguid which is needed to remove the mailbox completely
Remove-Mailbox -Database "<ExchangeDBName>" -StoreMailboxIdentity <ExchangeMBGuid>
```